# cant upload large files after Upgrading apache 2.4

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, apache-2.4, openssl, tomcat7

I am running `Tomcat 7` on top of the `Apache` and am using `Openssl` for secure http.

My root directory is docs:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs"
```

Inside `docs` I have folder `upload` where I upload all the files through my Tomcat app.

After upgrading to Apache 2.4 I am not able to upload large files any more. I can upload .txt, .xml and .csv files, though.

As a test, I took one of the .txt files and resized it to 6.~ KB and it failed to upload but making it 5.53KB worked. So it's gotta be file size issue.

error.log

```
[Thu Apr 02 11:23:02.520000 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 3272:tid 2392] ssl_engine_kernel.c(236): [client 192.111.4.55:64326] AH02034: Subsequent (No.9) HTTPS request received for child 249 (server myserver.com:443), referer: https://myserver.com/da8/jsp/Upload.jsp?Id=85&clear=true
[Thu Apr 02 11:23:02.520000 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3272:tid 2392] mod_authz_core.c(834): [client 192.111.4.55:64326] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives), referer: https://myserver.com/da8/jsp/Upload.jsp?Id=85&clear=true
[Thu Apr 02 11:23:18.538000 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 3272:tid 2392] (OS 10060)A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  : [client 192.111.4.55:64326] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Thu Apr 02 11:23:18.538000 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 3272:tid 2392] ssl_engine_io.c(999): [client 192.111.4.55:64326] AH02001: Connection closed to child 249 with standard shutdown (server myserver.com:443)
```

httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "D:/Apache Group/Apache2"

PidFile logs/httpd.pid

ScoreBoardFile logs/apache_runtime_status

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule mpm_winnt.c>
    ThreadsPerChild 250
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
    AcceptFilter http none
</IfModule>

ServerSignature off
ServerTokens Prod
SSLInsecureRenegotiation on

Listen 443

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

ServerAdmin admin@email.com
#internal IP address
ServerName 172.18.5.111
DocumentRoot "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs"

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None 
  Require all granted   
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None    
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/to_be_deleted">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/to_be_deleted/*">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Tomcat/webapps/da8">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted 
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Tomcat/webapps/da8/*">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted     
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/upload funding">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/upload funding/*">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Tomcat/webapps/da8">  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted  
</Directory> 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/*">  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted  
</Directory> 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Tomcat/webapps/da8">
    <Files "*.jsp">
    Require all granted 
    </Files>
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/upload funding"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride None 
    Require all denied 
</Directory> 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/upload funding"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted 
</Directory> 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/pubs"> 
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
     AllowOverride None 
     Require all denied 
 </Directory>  
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/pubs/*"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted 
</Directory> 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/uploadShippingAddressFiles">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride None 
    Require all denied  
</Directory>    
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/uploadShippingAddressFiles/*">  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted  
</Directory>   


<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/users/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
    Satisfy All
</Files>

UseCanonicalName Off

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
</IfModule>

#DefaultType text/plain
AddType text/css css

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog logs/error.log

LogLevel debug

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent


ServerSignature On

<IfModule mod_alias.c>

#Labels Alias 
Alias /labels/ "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/Labels/" 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/Labels/"> 
    Options FollowSymlinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted 
</Directory> 

#Upload Alias 
Alias /upload/ "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/upload/" 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/upload/"> 
    Options FollowSymlinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All  
    Require all granted 
</Directory> 
<Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs/upload/*"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted 
</Directory> 

    Alias /icons/ "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/icons/"

    <Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/icons">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /manual/ "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs/manual/"

    <Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs/manual">
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/cgi-bin/"

    <Directory "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
    AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
    AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
    AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
    AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
    AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
    AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
    AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
    AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
    AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
    AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
    AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
    AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
    AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
    AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
    AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
    AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
    AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
    AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
    AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
    AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core
    AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
    AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
    AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
    AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
    DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
    ReadmeName README
    HeaderName HEADER
    IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddEncoding x-compress Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip gz tgz
    AddLanguage da .dk
    AddLanguage nl .nl
    AddLanguage en .en
    AddLanguage et .ee
    AddLanguage fr .fr
    AddLanguage de .de
    AddLanguage el .el
    AddLanguage he .he
    AddCharset ISO-8859-8 .iso8859-8
    AddLanguage it .it
    AddLanguage ja .ja
    AddCharset ISO-2022-JP .jis
    AddLanguage kr .kr
    AddCharset ISO-2022-KR .iso-kr
    AddLanguage nn .nn
    AddLanguage no .no
    AddLanguage pl .po
    AddCharset ISO-8859-2 .iso-pl
    AddLanguage pt .pt
    AddLanguage pt-br .pt-br
    AddLanguage ltz .lu
    AddLanguage ca .ca
    AddLanguage es .es
    AddLanguage sv .sv
    AddLanguage cz .cz
    AddLanguage ru .ru
    AddLanguage tw .tw
    AddLanguage zh-tw .tw
    AddCharset Big5         .Big5    .big5
    AddCharset WINDOWS-1251 .cp-1251
    AddCharset CP866        .cp866
    AddCharset ISO-8859-5   .iso-ru
    AddCharset KOI8-R       .koi8-r
    AddCharset UCS-2        .ucs2
    AddCharset UCS-4        .ucs4
    AddCharset UTF-8        .utf8

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        LanguagePriority en da nl et fr de el it ja kr no pl pt pt-br ru ltz ca es sv tw
    </IfModule>
    AddType application/x-tar .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE 
RewriteRule .* - [F] 

TraceEnable off

Include "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/conf/httpd-jk.conf"

Mutex default ssl-cache
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin 
SSLSessionCache dbm:logs/ssl_gcache_data
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:!RC4+RSA:+HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXP

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  https://%{SERVER_NAME}
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Cache-Control "public"
  Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName myserver.com
    # HTTP Strict Transport Security (often abbreviated as HSTS) is a security
    # feature that lets a web site tell browsers that it should only be communicated
    # with using HTTPS, instead of using HTTP
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

    DocumentRoot "D:/Apache Group/Apache2/docs"
    SSLEngine On 
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/certificate.key
    SSLCACertificateFile  conf/ssl.crt/cabundle.crt 

    <Location /da8/pki>
        SSLVerifyClient require  
        SSLVerifyDepth 10 
        #SSLCACertificateFile  conf/ssl.crt/cabundle.crt 
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData 
    </Location> 

    JkExtractSSL On
    JkHTTPSIndicator HTTPS
    JkSESSIONIndicator SSL_SESSION_ID
    JkCIPHERIndicator SSL_CIPHER
    JkCERTSIndicator SSL_CLIENT_CERT
    JkEnvVar SSL_CLIENT_CERT SSL_CLIENT_CERT
    JkEnvVar SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0 SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0
    JKOptions +ForwardSSLCertChain

    JKMount /*.jsp dol
    JKMount /*.jsf dol
    JKMount /da8/faces/* dol
    JKMount /servlet/* dol
    JKMount /da8/servlet/* dol
    JKMount /jasperserver/* report
    SSLInsecureRenegotiation on
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know what this could be related to?

Comment: Have you tried adding    "Require all granted"  in your apache virtualhost ?

Comment: @hardik Yes I have it as 'Require all granted' but still not working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

It was Apache-Tomcat connector: AJP 1.3

After I added packetSize it worked.

```
 <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" packetSize="65536" />
```